# substring with bash and assign to a variable

Tags: bash

I execute the following command:

```
xinput  | grep Razer
```

the output is

```
⎜   ↳ Razer  Razer Abyssus                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

how can I get the id, assign it to a variable, so I can reuse it later in the script? The id is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe your command to sed:

```
yourvar=$(xinput | sed '/Razer/s/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
```

- `/Razer/`: when a line containing `Razer` is found
- `s/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/`: capture the id value and print it using backreference.

Comment: Hi.
I tried it...
yourvar=$(xinput | sed '/Touchpad/s/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')

but when echoing $yourvar, the the whole result of xinput is given, and not just the number following the "id=" sub-string.

I do have the following line in my xinput readout:
⎜   ↳ ELAN0518:01 04F3:31FC Touchpad           id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]

I'm using bash 5.1.16
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`grep` solution: Here if any line contains *Razer followed by id* then the ID is printed. Here `perl` regex is used by using `-p` flag of `grep` command. `\K` means ignore everything on left of it.

```
xinput  |grep -oP 'Razer.*id=\K[^ ]+'
12
```

Using `gawk`'s match function:

```
awk '/Razer/{match($0,/id=([^ ]+)/,a);print a[1]}'
12
```

Answer (score 0):

if you've `GNU AWK` or `gawk` you can do the below too.

```
id=$(xinput | awk '/Razer/{printf "%s",gensub(/^.*id=[[:digit:]]*).*$/,"\\1",$0)}')
```

Comment: Hi do you want to change your regex to  `/^.*id=([[:digit:]]*).*$/` ?

Comment: @PS :  You're right, It so happened that the `=` got trimmed when I copied the command from my VM.