# Using grep or sed to extract the numerical value of the 'device id' in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

A line from xinput says
⎜ ↳ ELAN0518:01 04F3:31FC Touchpad id=11 [slave pointer (2)]
I want to grab the number immediately following the "id=" part into a variable.

The proposed solution posted 6 years ago here:
[substring with bash and assign to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794227/substring-with-bash-and-assign-to-a-variable)
doesn't work and another proposed solution...

```
yourvar=$(xinput  |grep -oP 'Touchpad.*id=\K[^ ]+')
echo $yourvar
```

almost works but leaves trailing string, outputting:  "11   [slave"

How to adjust the grep command to just grab the number?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Try `Touchpad.*id=\K\S+` or `Touchpad.*id=\K\d+`

Comment: `xinput list --id-only 'ELAN0518:01 04F3:31FC Touchpad'`?

Comment: Thank you 'The fourth bird'.
Both   Touchpad.*id=\K\S+   and   Touchpad.*id=\K\d+
work.
And thank you also Cyrus as your solution works too.
Much appreciated all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `[^ ]+` which matches not a space. If there is for example a tab, you will match too much.

You might use for example `\S+` to match 1+ non whitespace chars:

```
Touchpad.*id=\K\S+
```

Or match 1 or more digits to a more precise pattern:

```
Touchpad.*id=\K\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use grep. Use sed.

```
xinput | sed -n -e 's/.*Touchpad.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'p
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen, the grep method works, as does your sed method, but can you help me understand why/when to use sed over grep?